# How to get variable out of Java while loop?

Tags: java, android, variables, while-loop, scope

I'm just learning Java and here I'm presented with this strange error message. In the code below:

```
while (phones_cursor.moveToNext())
{
  String name = phones_cursor.getString(phones_cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
}
Log.wtf("Name: ", name);
```

I'm get this message saying that "name" cannot be resolved to a variable. So I suppose name is local to the while loop. I wonder now however, how do I get this variable out of the while loop?

Comment: well...now you have 3 equal answers :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

define the variable outside of the loop

```
String name = null;

while (phones_cursor.moveToNext())
{
  name = phones_cursor.getString(phones_cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
}
Log.wtf("Name: ", name);
```

this is because every block (starting with `{` and ending with `}`) has it's own scope. but inner scope can access variables from outer scopes.

Comment: But keep in mind, that the above code iterates over all `phone_cursor` entries, but will only keep and print the value of the last entry.

Answer (score 4):

You have to define your variable outside the loop:

```
String name = null;

while (phones_cursor.moveToNext())
{
    name = phones_cursor.getString(phones_cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
}

Log.wtf("Name: ", name);
```

Answer (score 3):

Those variable is  out of scope.

In java the scope is restricted to `{}`.

Just move that `variable` declaration to top, so that they available further.

```
    String  name = null;
    while (phones_cursor.moveToNext())
    {
      name = phones_cursor.getString(phones_cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
    }
    Log.wtf("Name: ", name);
```

Prefer to read : [Block and Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/statements.html)